# Hide the small icon from the content view in push notification

Tags: android, push-notification

I am trying to hide the smallIcon from the content view and not from the status bar.
First I tried to hide it by writing the below code:

**.setSmallIcon(android.R.color.transparent)**

But the small icon is also not visible in the status bar.

Then I tried with:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(message))
                        .setContentText(message)
                        .setTicker("app_name")
                        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_name)
                        .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                        .setColor(getBaseContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
                                ....
                        Notification notification = mBuilder.build();

**int smallIconId = getResources().getIdentifier("icon_name", "drawable" , getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
notification.contentView.setViewVisibility(smallIconId, View.INVISIBLE);**
```

But It is not working. Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you may try to use custom notification layout

Comment: Yes, the issue is now fixed. I used the custom notification layout. Thank you @VladMatvienko

Answer (score 0):

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

      builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
                    .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setContentText("New Message");

//get custom layout
             RemoteViews notificationView = new RemoteViews(
                            getPackageName(),
                            R.layout.new_notification_card_layout
                    );
                    notificationView.setImageViewResource(R.id.notification_image, ResourceId);
         notificationView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, title);

        builder.setCustomBigContentView(notificationView);


     public int getNotificationIcon() {
            boolean useWhiteIcon = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP);
            return useWhiteIcon ? R.drawable.notification : R.drawable.notification_teal;
        }
```